# How to use a scr component factory?

Tags: java, components, prototype, factory, declarative-services

Here is my code:

1. An interface :

```
  public interface FieldProvisioner {
    Optional<FieldProvisionRecord> provisionField(FieldProvisionRecord record);
    FieldName getFieldName();
  }
```

2. An abstract Base Class that implements the above interface

`

```
import org.apache.felix.scr.annotations.Activate;
import org.apache.felix.scr.annotations.Component;
import org.apache.felix.scr.annotations.Properties;
import org.apache.felix.scr.annotations.Property;
import org.apache.felix.scr.annotations.Reference;
import org.apache.felix.scr.annotations.Service;
import org.osgi.framework.ServiceException;
import org.osgi.service.log.LogService;


@Properties({
  @Property(name=FieldProvisionerServiceBase.PROP_TCH, boolValue=false)
 })
@Component
@Service
public abstract class FieldProvisionerServiceBase implements FieldProvisioner {
public static final String PROP_TCH = "tch";

@Reference
protected LogService logger;
protected Boolean tch = false;

@Activate
public void activate(final Map<String, Object> properties) {
    OsgiServiceValueHelper helper = new OsgiServiceValueHelper(properties);
    tch = helper.getBoolean(PROP_TCH).orElse(false);
}

@Override
public Optional<FieldProvisionRecord> provisionField(final FieldProvisionRecord record,
        final Consumer<Exception> onError) {
        //some implementation
 }
}
```

3. Multiple classes like the one below (Soccer, Cricket, etc.) who extend the above abstract class

```
@Service
@Component
public class CricketProvisionerServiceImpl extends FieldProvisionerServiceBase {
    String FACTORY_NAME = "some.osgi.server.fieldprovision.CricketProvisionerServiceImpl";
    String FACTORY_FILTER = "(component.factory="+FACTORY_NAME+")";

    @Override
    public String getFactoryFilter() {
        return FACTORY_FILTER;
    }

    @Reference(target="(component.factory=\"tch.server.fieldprovision.CricketProvisionerServiceImpl\")")
    ComponentFactory fieldProvisionerFactory;

    @Override
    public FieldName getFieldName() {
        return FieldName.CRICKET;
    }

}
```

Now I have a Factory which gives me the class instance I need when I call it.

```
@Service
@Component
@References({
    @Reference(name="fieldProvisioners",
            bind="addService", unbind="removeService",
            referenceInterface=FieldProvisioner.class,
            cardinality=ReferenceCardinality.OPTIONAL_MULTIPLE, policy=ReferencePolicy.DYNAMIC)
})
public class FieldProvisionerFactoryImpl implements FieldProvisionerFactory {
    private List<FieldProvisioner> services = new CopyOnWriteArrayList<>();

    @Override
    public Optional<FieldProvisioner> getProvisionerService(final FieldName name) {
        Optional<FieldProvisioner> provisioner = services
                            .stream()
                            .filter(service -> service.getFieldName().equals(fieldDefinition.name))
                            .findFirst();
                    

        if (!provisioner.isPresent()) {
          //do something
        }

        return provisioner;
    }


    protected void addService(final FieldProvisioner check,
            final Map<String, Object> properties) {
        this.services.add(check);
    }

    protected void removeService(final FieldProvisioner check,
            final Map<String, Object> properties) {
        this.services.remove(check);
    }
}
```

The problem is every time I call FieldProvisionerFactory's getProvisionerService (with field name CRICKET), I expect a different instance of the service (CricketProvisionerServiceImpl). However, I get the same instance.

I am using older version of declarative services (with felix scr annotation - 1.9.12) which doesn't support the ReferenceScope. So I am trying to use componentFactory to get a different instance everytime a consumer calls.

Any thoughts on how to do it , any pointers, help?

Comment: Side note: please note that the SCR annotation are deprecated. Consider to use the standard OSGi annotations in the org.osgi.service.component.annotations.* package.

Comment: Thanks. Migration to new annotations (osgi R7) would happen, however, currently I want to make the code work with the scr annotations.